# What does "take me places" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning, songs

The expression "take me places" other similar phrases are used in many pop songs and seem to refer to somthing about relationships or sex. However, I have been unable to find a definition of the phrase in neither conventional nor slang dictionaries. What does it mean when it is used like in these songs:

*You don't have to pretend

I don't care where you've been*
(Get Low)

*So, shame on me now

Flew me to places I'd never been*
(I knew you were trouble)

*When we lie so still, but you're taking me places

Holding me onto you*
(Capital Letters)

To clarify, I'm not asking about the meaning of any of the songs in particular, but the phrase itself, as it appears to be a common and widely understood expression.

Comment: It's figurative -- the feeling of flying or visiting new places or such.  Basically like very pleasant dreaming.

Comment: Yes, it's sexual (as opposed to the old complaint "You never take me anywhere!"). Which *places*? Feeling high, turned on, out of body, or experiencing orgasm — perhaps for the first time, or more fully than before your partner *took you to places* like never before.

Comment: I once went to bed with a new girlfriend, and she said "I hope you'll make the earth move for me", and I said "Where do you imagine I am going to get a mechanical digger at this time of night?"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I imagine that was quite the mood-killer.

Comment: Well, things were never quite the same after that.

Comment: I did think of writing 'JCB' for British readers, or 'backhoe' for the Americans, but in the end I compromised.